LT6268-10 OpAmp Noise
Following on from my previous post , I printed the circuit as below however getting very noisy signal.
what am I doing wrong here?



Take a close look at how the demo board for this part is laid out: https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/user-guides/DC2414AF.PDF

You need to treat this like a high frequency circuit and layout appropriately. Those long, meandering traces, lack of ground plane and what looks like a coaxial connector for the photodiode are fine for the kinds of low frequency circuits you can breadboard but won't for such a fast opamp.

This ground is very very very (extremely) bad. Try to make ground connections short and ground areas as big as possible. Ground is very important, it should be like a stable base underneath a mechanic device. If it's not stable, everything will be wild.
Try doing it like this, gray area is all ground. I skipped the caps on power supply, put the as close to the chip as possible.


would ground bus be better?

"Ground" and power rails should be treated with equal respect.  No sense having a massive septic system if all your home's water comes from an undersized garden hose.

This is only true if you only look at current. But you should also look at electronics from emi point of view. Having small grounds is like having a pandolum on a base that's not stable. You will get some oscillations and stuff, definitely won't be nice pendulum movement. However if you put it on heavy base it will work nicely

@ChrisKnudsen I believe your "observation" to be profoundly wrong when it comes to controlling emissions on circuit boards.

@Andyaka I so shall stand corrected.  My fingers did act fast in quick response to the tape style inspired routing.
